# Probability of forming a even number

Tags: probability

Could someone explain and show how I would set this problem up?

A bag contains the digits $2,3,4,5,8,9$. A number is formed by picking three digits at random **WITHOUT** replacement. Find the probability that the number is even.

Comment: What connection does *the number* have with *the digits*?

Comment: The number is only 3 digits, and the digits cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Imagine picking the ones digit first.

Answer (score 0):

Three digits are picked in sequence and without replacement from the bag $\{2,3,4,5,8,9\}$

We are asked, in effect, "what is the probability that the third digit removed is even?"

Well, any one of those digits could be the third one removed with equal probability (no bias), and three of the six are even, so...

---

Or as Ross Millikan pointed out, we could use the first out of the bag as the units, the second as the tens, and the third for the hundreds place. The order of selection does not matter here.